# Prevent deletion of attachment on custom object

Tags: apex, trigger

I want to write an apex trigger to prevent the deletion of attachments.
I can think of Org Wide Defaults and Security of this custom object but how can I write a trigger for the same.

Comment: Perhaps you can post the code showing us what you've already tried, and we can help you with any errors you're getting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent related record deletion, except when parent record is being deleted](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/77815/prevent-related-record-deletion-except-when-parent-record-is-being-deleted)

Comment: Except removing `delete` permissions on `Attachment` is not really a viable solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can find out if an `Attachment` looks up to a specific `sObjectType` using the `getSObjectType` method on the `ParentId` value.

  - It's a good idea to add a `null` check beforehand because otherwise you end up validating that field as required with a `NullPointerException` instead of the standard validation for required fields.
- You can validate a trigger record by calling `addError`.
- According to Salesforce's own documentation on [Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm), validation should occur in a `before` trigger.

The `Id` check should look like:

```
if (record.ParentId != null && record.ParentId.getSObjectType() == MyObject__c.sObjectType)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a trigger on Attachment object. To identify attachment related to particular custom object you need check ParentId of Attachment.

```
trigger AttachmentTrigger on Attachment (before delete) {
    for(Attachment objA : Trigger.Old){
        if(/* Specify the condition*/){
            objA.addError('You can not delete attachment');
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to add a trigger in before delete and throw an exception causing deletion fails.

```
trigger CustomTrigger on Attachment (before delete) {

   for(Attachment a : Trigger.old){
      //sample validation
      if(a.ParentId == 'check for some sobject'){
         a.addError('Record cannot be deleted');
      }
   }
}
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_exceptions.htm

Instead of custom you should use Attachment object: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000181538&language=en_US

Comment: They're trying to validate the `Attachment` records.

Comment: Yes, but it´s just the same. Anyway I modified the snippet to Attachment object.