# Unable to restrict users to delete attachments sharing from quick actions

Tags: permissions, attachment, quickaction

Some users need to attach files to opportunities even though they don't own the record. So these users are uploading through quick actions like file in opportunity record.

We are restricting users to delete attachments. But when they share from quick action they have access to delete those attachments. Is there any way to restrict users to delete even if they shared from quick actions?

Comment: Requires a before delete trigger on the contentDocumentLink object.  No way to restrict via declarative means.

Comment: You can refer this link https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/134085/prevent-deletion-of-attachment-on-custom-object

Comment: No way to configure delete attachments permissions in a point-and-click way?